# No output is coming not even error java with jri call to R

Tags: java, eclipse, r, jri

Below is my code

```
package org.quad.test;

import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;

public class JRT {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Cannot load R");
        // new R-engine
        Rengine re = new Rengine(new String[] {}, false, null);
        if (!re.waitForR()) {
            System.out.println("Cannot load R");
            return;
        } else {
            System.out.println(" load R");
        }

        // print a random number from uniform distribution
        System.out.println(re.eval("runif(1)").asDouble());
        System.out.println("Cannot load R");
        // done...
        re.end();

    }

}
```

Above program runs fine but no output

please help as i am new to java with r integration....

Comment: I guess it is waiting for `R` then

Comment: Thanks for reply.I think you are right but r is already running,then why it is not getting called

Comment: eclipse console shows <terminated>JRT...

Comment: how is that possible?  Not showing anything else?

Comment: thanks ,but it is not showing anything else written after Rengine re = new Rengine(new String[] {""}, false, null); line

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](http://www.rosuda.org/r/nightly/javadoc/org/rosuda/JRI/Rengine.html#Rengine%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20boolean,%20org.rosuda.JRI.RMainLoopCallbacks%29)

The correct constructor for an `REngine` is

```
public Rengine(String[] args,
               boolean runMainLoop,
               RMainLoopCallbacks initialCallbacks)
```

so you code should be

```
Rengine re = new Rengine(args, false, null);
```

Please note that R requires the presence of certain arguments (e.g. --save or --no-save or equivalents), so passing an empty list usually doesn't work.

Comment: I changed and run it as  Rengine re = new Rengine (new String [] {"--vanilla"}, false, null); ,Still same no output and program getting terminated

Comment: Finally solved if using eclipse then this link works http://www.studytrails.com/RJava-Eclipse-Plugin/                                  if not using eclipse this link works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100875/java-r-interface-jri-setup