# Not finding libraries for JRI

Tags: java, r

I set up a JRI project for NetBeans 7.4 using 32-bit R 3.0.2 and Java  jdk1.7.0_45, on Windows 7, using the steps outlined [here](http://www.studytrails.com/blog/r-and-java-jri-using-netbeans/).

When I called

```
Rengine.versionCheck()
```

I got the following

Cannot find JRI native library!
Please make sure that the JRI native library is in a directory listed in java.library.path.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\library\rJava\jri\jri.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1880)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
at org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine.<clinit>(Rengine.java:19)
at rjava.RJava.main(RJava.java:40)
Java Result: 1
```

Following the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100875/java-r-interface-jri-setup?rq=1), I copied all of the dlls from

```
C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\bin\i386
```

to the directory containing java.exe.  I also right-cliked on the project and selected

```
 Properties:Run:VM Options
```

and added

```
 -Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\library\rJava\jri;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\library\rJava\jri\i386"
```

The problem persisted.  I tried prepending the following to my code.

```
 System.loadLibrary("jri");
```

This resulted in

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\library\rJava\jri\jri.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1965)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1890)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1880)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
at rjava.RJava.main(RJava.java:39)
 Java Result: 1
```

I have done everything suggested [here](https://sdqweb.ipd.kit.edu/wiki/User:Krogmann/R_from_Java) but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

I had to restart NetBeans.  That fixed the problems.

In fact, I found this part unnecessary.

```
 Properties:Run:VM Options
 -Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\library\rJava\jri;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.0.2\library\rJava\jri\i386"
```